# can i access tor sites access using vpn proxies?

Tags: proxy

I wanted to visit .onion sites without using tor.
Because tor speed  is very  slow.
Can i access tor sites using vpn-proxies? 
And what types of proxies i need to use?
is it is HTTP/SOCK4/5?
Or all types of vpn-proxies support darknet access?
i dont aware about my security.
 encryption doesn't matter, If speed is better.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.
You can access .onion sites only using Tor.
Those a hosted within Tor and cannot be accessed without using Tor.

Or you can access tor using https://tor2web.org/ if you don't care about anonymity.

---

Also take a look at this: https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services
Its explains how does hidden services works.